# Error when trying to use zeep to connect to Netsuite

Tags: python, netsuite, zeep

I'm writing a Python application that is to connect to Netsuite (WSDL) and then INSERT data into the table. I'm trying to use zeep to connect to our Netsuite server and I get this error:

```
python3.6 /xxx/python-netsuite/netsuite/client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 565, in _get_component
return items[qname]
KeyError: <lxml.etree.QName object at 0x10e9bd850>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/xxx/python-netsuite/netsuite/client.py", line 2, in <module>
from netsuite.service import (client,
File "/xxx/python-netsuite/netsuite/service.py", line 13, in <module>
Passport = model('ns1:Passport')
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 263, in get_type
return self.wsdl.types.get_type(name)
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 140, in get_type
return self._get_instance(qname, 'get_type', 'type')
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 243, in _get_instance
raise last_exception
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 239, in _get_instance
return method(qname)
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 523, in get_type
return self._get_component(qname, self._types, 'type')
File "/xxx/.virtualenvs/for-netsuite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 580, in _get_component
location=self._location)
zeep.exceptions.LookupError: No type 'Passport' in namespace 
urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com. Available types are: 

{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}RecordType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchRecordType, 
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}GetAllRecordType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}GetCustomizationType, 
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}InitializeType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}InitializeRefType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}InitializeAuxRefType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}DeletedRecordType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}AsyncStatusType,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchStringFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchLongFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchTextNumberFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchDoubleFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchDateFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchDate,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}DurationUnit,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}CalendarEventAttendeeResponse,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}GetSelectValueFilterOperator,
{urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SignatureAlgorithm

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my client.py

```
import ns_config
from netsuite.service import (client,
                          RecordRef,
                          ApplicationInfo,
                          Passport)


def make_passport():
role = RecordRef(internalId=ns_config.NS_ROLE)
return Passport(email=ns_config.NS_EMAIL,
                password=ns_config.NS_PASSWORD,
                account=ns_config.NS_ACCOUNT,
                role=role)


def login():
app_info = ApplicationInfo(applicationId=ns_config.NS_APPID)
passport = make_passport()
login = client.service.login(passport=passport, _soapheaders={'applicationInfo': app_info})

print('Login Response: ', login.status)
return client, app_info


passport = make_passport()
client, app_info = login()
```

The WSDL_URL is this: https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_1_0/netsuite.wsdl. Which is the version of Netsuite that we have.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which zeep version are you on? I have noticed that in zeep version `0.22.1`, `Passport` does lie in `ns1` as in your code. But in newer version `2.5.0` `Passport` lies in `ns0`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct namespace for Passport is:

```
urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
```

not the one in your error message:

```
urn:types.core_2017_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com
```

I'm new to zeep and netsuite, but I have noticed that so far, wherever the type of a parameter or header is known, I can just pass a plain dict with string keys and string or nested dict values, and zeep will turn it into the correct typed xml, without me having to give namespaces or instantiate and link up xsd objects. Might help simplify your code.

Comment: just came across this answer of yours. Guessing you might help me at https://stackoverflow.com/q/50461876/1781024