# Netsuite namespace conflict (core_2017_2.platform vs accounting_2017_2.lists)

Tags: python, soap, netsuite, zeep, suitetalk

I want to post a journal entry to Netsuite from my Python script. I am using zeep to talk to SuiteTalk.

I am new to Netsuite and I am new to SOAP. Following on internet examples, I managed to add a test customer via Python script using the below code:

```
def make_app_info(client):
    AppInfo = client.get_type('ns4:ApplicationInfo')
    app_info = AppInfo(applicationId=NS_APPID)
    return app_info


def make_passport(client):
    RecordRef = client.get_type('ns0:RecordRef')
    Passport = client.get_type('ns0:Passport')
    role = RecordRef(internalId=NS_ROLE)

    return Passport(email=NS_EMAIL,
                    password=NS_PASSWORD,
                    account=NS_ACCOUNT,
                    role=role)


def login_client():
    client = Client(WSDL_URL)
    login = client.service.login(passport=make_passport(client), _soapheaders={'applicationInfo': make_app_info(client)})
    return client
```

The `WSDL_URL` I am using is https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_2_0/netsuite.wsdl

Using the above client the below code adds the customer:

```
def add_customer():
    client = login_client()

    Customer = client.get_type('ns13:Customer')
    customer = Customer(
        lastName='Prasad',
        firstName='Vikas',
        email='vikasprasad@example.com',
        companyName='Test Company'
    )

    client.service.add(customer)

add_customer()
```

The above adds the `Customer` successfully to the Netsuite account and I can see it in the list on the webapp.
Continuing on the above example, I wrote this code to add `JournalEntry`:

```
def get_record_by_type(client, type, internal_id):
    RecordRef = client.get_type('ns0:RecordRef')

    record = RecordRef(internalId=internal_id, type=type)
    response = client.service.get(record,
        _soapheaders={
            'applicationInfo': make_app_info(client),
            'passport': make_passport(client),
        }
    )
    r = response.body.readResponse
    if r.status.isSuccess:
        return r.record

def add_journal_entry():
    client = login_client()

    # get subsidiary by internal id
    subsidiary = get_record_by_type(client, 'subsidiary', '1')
    print(subsidiary)    # This prints a valid subsidiary having internal id 1

    # create two journal entry lines
    JournalEntryLine = client.get_type('ns31:JournalEntryLine')
    credit_line = JournalEntryLine(account=get_record_by_type(client, 'account', '1'), credit=100)
    debit_line = JournalEntryLine(account=get_record_by_type(client, 'account', '2'), debit=100)
    print(credit_line)    # This prints credit_line with a valid account having internal id 1
    print(debit_line)    # This prints debit_line with a valid account having internal id 2

    JournalEntryLineList = client.get_type('ns31:JournalEntryLineList')
    journal_entry_line_list = JournalEntryLineList(line=[credit_line, debit_line])

    JournalEntry = client.get_type('ns31:JournalEntry')
    journal_entry = JournalEntry(subsidiary=subsidiary, lineList=journal_entry_line_list)

    client.service.add(journal_entry, _soapheaders={'passport': make_passport(client),
                   'applicationInfo': make_app_info(client)})  # Fails on this line.

add_journal_entry()
```

This fails on the call `client.service.add(...)` with the error:

> zeep.exceptions.Fault: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Expected
>   {urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}name, found
>   {urn:accounting_2017_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com}name

I am sure this is something silly in the world of SOAP, but I am not sure which direction to debug into. Why is there a difference between the expected and the found one? I have nowhere mentioned any specific namespaces. Its just WSDL `v2017_2_0` and all the `client.get_type()` call are made on top of this. Where is this error coming from?

Have asked the same question at Netsuite user group:
https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/web-services-suitetalk/434717-netsuite-namespace-conflict#post434717

**UPDATE:**
Based on @Justin W's answer it turns out, that instead of fetching the `subsidiary` and `account`s by their `internalId` from Suitetalk and then adding them in the request, I can directly tell Suitetalk the `type` and the `internalId` using a `RecordRef` and Suitetalk will understand what `subsidiary` and `account`s to use.

i.e. `subsidiary = get_record_by_type(client, 'subsidiary', '1')` can be changed to `subsidiary = RecordRef(internalId='1', type='subsidiary')`

Similarly

```
credit_line = JournalEntryLine(account=get_record_by_type(client, 'account', '1'), credit=100)
debit_line = JournalEntryLine(account=get_record_by_type(client, 'account', '2'), debit=100)
```

can be changed to

```
credit_line = JournalEntryLine(account=RecordRef(internalId='1', type='account'), credit=100)
debit_line = JournalEntryLine(account=RecordRef(internalId='2', type='account'), debit=100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's probably that your `get_account()` returns an `Account` but `JournalEntryLine.account` is supposed to be a `RecordRef` (actually, the same problem for `get_subsidiary()` as well)

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton for the response. It worked. Adding an update in the question about the same.

Comment: may be you can help out over here too: https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/suitebundler/435019-suitebundle-vs-web-services